# Perl Script not saving C outfile

Tags: c, perl

I've been adding a plugin to an existing project, and the thing is tied together with a perl script. I'm trying to add my C program into the perl script to make an output file, but the output is garbage or missing.

My executable is called `Interpolate` and when it's in the same folder as the perl script it's working just fine

```
./Interpolate inv.tracking_log
```

Is how the command is run. It should produce an intermediate filecalled `tmp.log`, and a final file called `out.txt`. When I run it in the directory it does just fine, both files are as they should be.

So then I added a system call into the perl script (I barely (if that) know perl):

```
print("./Interpolate $inVideoFile");      //prints like the command (just a test)
my $interCall = system("./Interpolate $inVideoFile");
```

When running it from within the perl script, the `tmp.log` file is mostly garbage, and `out.txt` is missing entirely. I do realize out is most likely missing because it has a dependency on the `tmp.log` file. Is there a perl 'gotchya' that I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: Not sure but try running with absolute path.

Comment: try oneliner: perl -e "system("./Interpolate inv.tracking_log");' and check the result. If it is bad, the problem has some deeper roots, if ok, the problem is somewhere in the remainder of your perl program.

Comment: That works fine. I'll try and track down the guy who wrote the script today if I can't figure it out for a bit. Thanks

Comment: Try separating the command and the arg by a comma:  my $intercall = system("./Interpolate", $inVideoFile");

Comment: Where are you calling the perl script from? Make sure your working directory is the same. Try adding `print \`cmd\`` above your `system` call to find out where you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
system("./Interpolate $inVideoFile");
```

should be

```
system("./Interpolate", $inVideoFile);
```

If you still have a problem after fixing that, `$inVideoFile` doesn't contain what it should, or there's a bug in your C program. (What is the return value of the `system` call?)

Comment: Only wondering why this: perl -e 'system("ls -1 /etc/ | sort -r");' working ok e.g., when the command name and args are *not* entered as an list.

Comment: system has three syntaxes. 1) Takes a shell command, 2) Takes a program name followed by 1 or more arguments, 3) Takes a program name and zero or more arguments. Are you claiming that `$inVideoFile` is misnamed and actually contains a shell literal that evaluates to the file name? If so, then ignore my recommendation. If `$inVideoFile` contains a file name, then you have a bug.